# Update regedit AutoConfigURL variable at IE with vbscript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, proxy, refresh, regedit

With a visual basic script file in a ms-dos command window i change the REGEDIT var `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL`, but i have to reestart the IE to see that value in IE-internet config -> connections -> LAN configuration.

C:>cscript proxypac.vbs :

```
RegLocate = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL"
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite RegLocate, "http://10.11.12.13/proxy.pac", "REG_SZ"
```

How can i refresh IE connection Regedit settings using VBS in a command window without restarting IE ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reflect any changes in IE application which done in the registry key via VB Script without restarting the IE application.

IE will not apply those changes immediately while IE is already running. IE will read new values on starting time.

There is no any command available to do this thing.

So there is no any other option and you need to restart the IE application to see the modified registry values.